# Beautiful Soup find all has a max buffer size?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to collect all garment images in a certain webpage, but I am only retrieving 32 out of 168.

Is this related with some dynamic property of the web that I might be missing or with some max buffer size?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://zalando.com/ropa-de-mujer/?p=2'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
garments = soup.find_all("div", class_="cat_articleContain-1Z60A")

for garment in garments:
    images = garment.find('img', class_='cat_image-1byrW')
    print(images['src'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I see the view-source of this website , After 32. items other items is in JSON
So In this case using `selenium` is more powerful.If you don't installed yet you can install in http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

> URL is not accessable on my country so change url in urs.

```
from selenium import webdriver


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, 
executable_path=r'chromedriver path') 

driver.get("https://www.zalando.es/ropa-de-mujer/?p=2") 
x = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.cat_articleContain-1Z60A") ## div . means class (# for id)
href = [link.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href') for link in x]
img = [link.find_element_by_css_selector('img').get_attribute('src') for link in x]

print(img)

driver.close() // Close page
```

**OUTPUT :**

[u'https://mosaic03.ztat.net/vgs/media/catalog-lg/VE/12/1A/0N/4Q/11/VE121A0N4-Q11@10.jpg', u'https://mosaic04.ztat.net/vgs/media/catalog-lg/DE/12/1D/0H/LK/11/DE121D0HL-K11@19.jpg', u'https://mosaic03.ztat.net/vgs/media/catalog-lg/JE/12/1B/00/XG/11/JE121B00X-G11@10.jpg', u'https://mosaic04.ztat.net/vgs/media/catalog-lg/CL/92/1C/0H/OG/11/CL921C0HO-G11@10.jpg', u'https://mosaic03.ztat.net/vgs/media/catalog-lg/M3/22/1C/0P/NQ/11/M3221C0PN-Q11@10.jpg',

**...**  **Up to 84**

> By the way there are 84 items when reach load more button not 168